# Distinguishing arguments and explanations

Tags: logic

For this question suppose that an argument is a rationale in which the reason presents evidence in support of a claim made in the conclusion, and an explanation is a rationale in which the reason presents a cause of some fact represented by the conclusion.

I'd like to verify that my classifications below are correct.

1. Illegal immigrants pay local sales taxes, and many of them also pay state, local, and federal income tax and Social Security tax.  They also purchase items from local merchants, increasing the amount these merchants pay in taxes.  In addition, they work for low salaries, which increases the earnings of their employers and the amount of taxes these employers pay.  Thus, it is not correct to say that illegal immigrants contribute nothing to the communities in which they live.

This is an argument because the conclusion is the last sentence and the premises are the sentences before that and they are supportive evidence of the conclusion.

2. A rainbow sometimes occurs after a storm because the droplets of water in the air refract and reflect rays of light from the sun.  The angle of refraction is different for different wavelengths of light, and this accounts for the separation of colors in the rainbow.

This is an explanation because it is explaining the rainbow.

3. The selling of human organs, such as hearts, kidneys, and corneas, should be outlawed.  If this practice is allowed to get a foothold, people in desperate financial straits will start selling their own organs to pay their bills. Alternately, those with a criminal bent will take to killing healthy young people and selling their organs on the black market.

This is an argument because nothing is being explained

4. The dinosaurs are extinct because a large comet or asteroid struck the earth some 65 million years ago.  This event caused a large cloud of dust to rise into the sky and block the light from the sun.  As a result, photosynthesis was blocked, which in turn drastically lowered world temperatures.

This is an explanation because they are explaining why dinosaurs are extinct

Comment: This probably depends on the conventions about "argument" and "explanation" used in your class, so you should add background information to your post. On usual meaning, I do not see why 3 is not an explanation, it explains why something should be outlawed. And generally, why can't something be an argument *and* an explanation? My guess is that you are supposed to mark something as "explanation" unless it has keywords to indicate clear premises-inferences-conclusion structure, in which case your marks are reasonable.

Comment: An argument is a rationale in which the reason presents evidence in support of a claim made in the conclusion and an explanation is a rationale in which the reason presents a cause of some fact represented by the conclusion

Comment: Yes, if this is the distinction, your labels look right.

Comment: How is number 3 an explanation

Comment: What is the other definition of arguments and explanation

Comment: The usual meaning of explanation is vaguer and broader: anything that answers a "why". "An explanation is a set of statements usually constructed to describe a set of facts which clarifies the causes, context, and consequences of those facts", says [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explanation). So 1 explains why immigrants contribute, 3 explains why outlawing organ selling is beneficial, etc. An argument is something more shaped, a list of inferences leading from premises to a conclusion. But nothing stops it from also explaining why the conclusion holds.

Comment: Your examples of arguments all involve moral claims, while your examples of explanations are factual claims--did you intend this distinction, or do you think there can be explanations of moral claims and arguments for factual claims? I wonder what the difference between an argument and an explanation would be for a factual claim, is there anything more to it than whether the claim is widely-accepted or controversial?

Comment: in the dictionary.

Comment: Only example one is an argument. It is directly a counter example of why immigrants do contribute something to the communities they live. This is the exact opposite of the wording in the example. It proves by counter example the proposition immigrants do not contribute to the communities where they live is False. Notice this argument is an INDUCTIVE ARGUMENT. it is not as strong as a deductive argument. Examples 2,3 & 4 are NOT TYPICALLY classified as arguments. They are news reporting basically. This information is descriptive of how things are. None are expressing premises or a conclusion.

Comment: @ Hypnosifl . Consider this argument. (1) The ground is wet. (2) Therefore it has rainded. The fact that the ground is wet does not explain why it has rained. It's not a cause of this fact, but an effect ( or , at least, a supposed effect). It only gives reason to believe it has rained.

Comment: Very interesting positions, thank you for the posts.

Comment: @RayLittleRock - Maybe the difference between an argument and an explanation is just that an explanation is for something that's widely agreed is correct (like an established scientific claim), where as an argument is for something more controversial or uncertain (like a moral claim, or like your example where wet ground may increase the subjective likelihood that it rained but there could be other plausible explanations).

Answer (score 0):

I have some issues with your initial assumptions. As I see it, an 'argument' and an 'explanation' are better thought of as two separate language games:

- An 'argument' is an effort to convince someone of a novel or non-intuitive position or viewpoint
- An 'explanation' is an effort to describe for someone a common, accepted, or intuitive position or viewpoint

An explanation becomes an argument when it meets resistance or disbelief; an argument reduces to an explanation when no one challenges it. The two are almost identical, except for the intent of the people involved in the verbal act (the language game the people are playing).

For instance, your propositions 2 and 4 are probably viewed by most people *now* as explanations, but there was clearly a point in each case where someone had to *argue* that these ideas should be accepted as valid. I don't know when the 'diffraction' theory of rainbow formation was first raised — Wikipedia puts the idea anywhere from the 11th to the 13th century — but the 'asteroid extinction' theory was first proposed in 1980, and was met with stiff resistance in the scientific community until the evidence started to mount. It had to be *argued* for most of a decade until it became accepted enough that people began merely *explaining* it as a given fact.